# How to process messages parallel in spring integration in multiple processes while they must be processed sequential on a correlation id

Tags: spring, spring-integration

A cluster with multiple processes must process messages sequential on receive time for the same correlation id. For different correlation ids they must be processed parallel. How to solve this with spring integration?

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't have enough info about your data and what really are those sequences and if you need an aggregation for them, but mostly your requirements sound like a solution provided for us by Apache Kafka.

1. You can have a cluster of consumers for specific topic in specific group.
2. According to the consumer group management partitions in the topic are going to be distributed between your consumer instances.
3. If to follow Spring for Apache Kafka recommendations, one partition will be handled by one thread, therefore sequentially. While different partitions are handled in parallel by different threads (probably even in different processes).
4. So, when you publish your messages into this topic, you need to make sure to map your correlation id to the Kafka record key - and messages with the same correlation id are going to land in the same partition.
5. It is really hard to reach a true parallelism when we try to make it based on some business key from data. Therefore you need to agree to deal with some interleaving sequences in the same partition.

See more info in respective Spring Integration module: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/kafka.html

Comment: Thanks, currently I am using spring integration with jdbc backend with a poller. That works fine for 1 process. Preferable I want to use polling with jdbc, but somehow want to be sure that when using pollers in multiple processes that they do not consume messages with the same correlation id at the same time. (You could see all messages with the same correlation id as a stream which must be processed in same order as that they arrive).

Comment: Right, I know what you mean, but that JDBC-backed queue does not give us sequential guaranties in cluster. It is possible only via exclusive consumer which is out of Spring Integration scope and has to be addressed using respective dedicated libraries and messaging middleware, like the mentioned Apache Kafka. The JDBC queue is really an anti-pattern. You cannot achieve what you want in a cluster just with plain Spring Integration and JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Spring, it is a design question. Here is an idea: create a `Map<CorrelationId, List<Nessage>>` and in your `List<Message>` sort your messages by received time. Than create a number of message handling proceseses equial to your Map size (number of ids). Each process should handle a list of messages for one particular ID in sequential manner, but for different IDs your processes will run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to implement it with spring integration *and* it must working with multiple processes (vm's).